# Redis / Jedis: Cluster versus Pool

Tags: java, redis, jedis, sentinel

I am new to Redis, Jedis and Sentinel. I am trying to educate myself using numerous web sites, code snippets and tutorials.

I have a simple understanding problem:

Some sources speak about a Redis Cluster, Jedis however uses the term Pools. 
Are they the same thing? Or are they conceptually different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a conceptual differentiation between cluster and pool independent of redis and jedis here:
[Difference between pool and cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333901/difference-between-pool-and-cluster)